# Replacement for default Visual Studio Resx editor?

Tags: visual-studio

Anyone has suggestion for something that's better than Visual Studio default Resource string editor? Not looking for standalone Resx editor, just something that has better navigation between strings in Grid, better support for long strings, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: An XML editor?  There's one built into VS, right-click the .resx file, Open With.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This tool [ResEx](http://resex.codeplex.com/) inherited from Dimitris Papadimitriou is awesome.
Features I love:

1. Warns you if you are missing a {0} that is defined in the default resx file
2. Translate side by side
3. Warnings about shortcut characters

Comment: :) And have you tried new version with autotranslate -> http://resex.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, ResEx does not support adding new items to a Resx file. Thus it may be suitable to create new translations, but it's not really useful during development.

Answer (score 20):

[ResXManager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68) is another great free tool that integrates with Visual Studio.

From the site:

> You can quickly navigate through all resource files and view the content in a well-arranged data grid. It makes it easy to find untranslated strings or clean up orphaned entries. All strings can be quickly edited in place, ...

The tool is still updated and is available as VS2012-2017 extension and standalone executable to support VS2010 and older.

[image]

Comment: I specially like the export/import function to Excel, which makes it easy to get the files translated by people that do not have Visual Studio or direct access to the source files (which is often useful because then it does not have to be developers that do the translations...)

Answer (score 16):

A wee bit on the late side:
I find [Zeta Resource editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com) very useful.
More or less the same feature, and quite polished:

- Auto-translate
- Warning of inconsistent formatting arguments
- Load from VS solution
- Nesting of translations
- Colors indicating translation status

Addendum: it seems Google Translate / Bing Translate have changed into being a paid services. Auto-translation is still available, yet you need an API key and billing information.

Comment: I found it very nice to work with translations, it can open multiple resx files one for each language and will present them side by side.

Comment: I love this tool, even if it's standalone. It saved me hours of editing stupid resx files!

Comment: It was unstable and hard to use with existing resource files. The automatic add from Visual Studio failed. Should be possible to just open a resx file and have all the related languages automatically linked without having to create a propritary project file.

Comment: Sure, it has it's drawbacks, but it's developer was quite communicative when I had some questions back in the day I was into this. Have you tried the forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zeta-resource-editor

Comment: Too bad we have to click on the `Open resource files` button. Configuring Windows to open .resx files automatically with this software doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is a extension for Visual Studio Code which works pretty well and it's cross platform.
https://github.com/DominicVonk/vscode-resx