# Are there web editing tools that can work with ASP.NET that a layman can use?

Tags: asp.net

We have an ASP.NET website that is integrated with a back-end system in a few key places but is largely brochure-ware. The site is localized using resx resources, tied to ASP.NET controls. We would like to hand some of the editing duties to non-developers, but Visual Studio is too intimidating an interface. Expression Web would be perfect, but it does not appear to support localization.

Is there anything else out there that we could try?

**UPDATE**

To clarify, I am *not* looking for a resource editor, but rather a web page editor that understands the composition of an ASP.NET web site and its localized web controls, and can present a WYSIWYG editable surface to a non-programmer, while doing the right thing with resource files behind the scenes.

Comment: Are you just looking for a .resx editor or does the tool need to be capable of other things as well, if so what?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but this other question mention a tool for editing resources outside Visual Studio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067635/replacement-for-default-visual-studio-resx-editor

Comment: Adobe Dream Weaver might fit your needs. The Web designer at my work place uses that and he doesn't have any programming experience. Technically he is a marketing guy. Dream weaver has many templates and plug ins designed to make things easy for non programmers. It can read and write asp.net and classic asp. When the guy designs something that marketing approves it is very easy for me to add all the real programming logic to it. Sheesh, I sound like I work for Adobe

Answer (score 0):

There is [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) which is an Open Source Visual Studio clone. It works much like Visual Studio, but is much simpler.

[image]

It has a built-in RESX editor and basic syntax highlighting. It does not support however navigating from a resource string in an ASPX page to the resource in the RESX file directly.

According to [Wikipedia, SharpDevelop allows for plugins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop), but I do not know of any with such navigation features.