# Cascading Updates to .Resx file

Tags: visual-studio, localization, resx

Are there any mechanisms available out of the box with Visual Studio (pre-compilation, not using code) that allow changes in one .resx localization file to cascade to others? It's a manual process to add the string to multiple files. I've seen something similar done with .config files, where they're nested and at compile time the children config files overwrite the parent.

Comment: Not a "mechanism", a localization service normally takes care of it.  You only maintain your own language and send it out to get it translated.  They'll use very expensive tooling like Passolo to speed it up, the kind that your boss never approves.  Cobbling your own together, meh, your time better be very cheap to compete with what they can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An indirect answer to my question is use a different resource editor, such as the one outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25127820/719539, the ResXManager extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b64e04c-e8de-4b97-8358-06c73a97cc68

It highlights missing items, which suited my need.